# How to create a variable with an initial value in LLVM IR?

Tags: initialization, llvm-ir

So in LLVM IR we can create a variable giving it the returned value of an instruction:

```
%1 = mul i32 %A, %B
```

But how to create a variable giving it an initial value?

It C++ it would be:

```cpp
int x = 5;
```

However this kind of initialization seems not allowed in LLVM IR:

```
%x = i32 5
```

`llc` compiler emits an error:

```
 error: expected instruction opcode
    %x = i32 5
         ^
```

Does this mean that variables in LLVM IR can only have the returned values of instructions? What if I want to set a variable to some known predefined initial value?

Can it be done without using `alloca`, without creating a variable on the stack?

Comment: Note that %1 is not a variable, though; it is a value. Even if you were to create a value named %x that was equal to 5, it would not be modifiable. If you want an actual program variable whose value can be changed, you need to either create an alloca, a call to a heap allocation function, or a global variables, and use the load/store instructions.

Comment: Try looking at clang's llvm output for variable initialization in C/C++ here https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @DwightGuth Yes I know that `%1` is a virtual register. It is an rvalue with no memory location. I was just wondering if it was possible to just outright assign the `%1` to an initial value without doing the extra `add` instruction, and without taking up memory, either in the form of `alloca`, or global variables, or dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is declare a constant global variable and hope that the optimizer will inline each usage of it. It would look something like this:

```
@var = private constant i32 5

...

%var = load i32, i32* @var
```

The downside of this, however, is that you would not be able to use %var in constant expressions. It also would not be modifiable, but then, no value in llvm of the form %var is modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we're working in a static single assign framework, The answer of making it a constant is a good one, since that value is never going to be reassigned anyway.

But if you really want to load a constant value directly into a register in a single instruction without declaring a constant, there is no direct way to do that, but you could simply add a value to 0.

```
%x = add i32 5, 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't that actually have an additional `add` instruction? Can we initialize a virtual register variable without having the `add` instruction? Seems like an inefficiency ...

Comment: Of course it would.  No, there is no way to just put a value into a register unless there's something that I haven't found.  I'm just giving the best option I know of given the language as it stands.  You're totally welcome to advocate for changing the language, but that's not within my ability to do.  In practice, the extra instruction will likely get removed in an optimization pass anyway.